# When should I take some piled downvotes seriously and when should I consider them to be serial downvoting?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

Around 30 minutes ago four of my answers were downvoted. They're totally unrelated, so I'm assuming they're the result of a serial downvote.

My question isn't whether this can be resolved (although that would be nice); my question is - at what point should I assume it is a serial downvote and not just a genuine case of downvoting? At what point should I raise it as an issue? Or does Stack Overflow have measures in place to stop serial downvoting somehow?

Comment: In short: don't waste your time over this. It happens to everyone. Just keep posting and don't let the downvotes sting too much.

Comment: Hmm @sha; that's intellectually true but not actually. I got my first downvote in 6 months the other day. There were 2, a minute apart. They weren't reversed by the serial downvote script and it happens multiple times. It still hurts, even though there's nothing I can do....

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: Of course, two downvotes in quick succession doesn't necessarily point to abuse.

Comment: @ben I didn't say it doesn't hurt, just advised not to let it affect you too much and stop you from going on. As for serial downvote script, it starts working only for 3+ (or more) downvotes in a row afaik. (which isn't a big secret anymore :/)